# Bar plot for each column in a data frame in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to produce bar plots for each column in a data frame.

I tried the following code to produce plot for a single column and it's working fine.

```
ggplot(df, aes(colName, ..count..)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = colName), position = "dodge")
```

But it's not working if i put it in a for loop to produce plot for each column in the data frame.

```
for(col in names(df)){
    print(col)
    ggplot(df, aes(col, ..count..)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = col), position = "dodge")
  }
```

I don't want to hard code the column names in the code and I don't want to develop a separate function.

Comment: You want a barplot with only one bar? Hence for each column? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Elias I want the bar plot for every columns in the data frame in a single window

Comment: @tjebo no..it's not answering my question

Comment: All the solutions given in the linked thread should work perfectly fine. Please kindly elaborate why it does not answer the question.

Comment: Okay. I'll check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create plots for each column of your dataframe using `lapply`. To refer to column name as variable in ggplot code use `.data` :

```
library(ggplot2)

lapply(names(df), function(col) {
  ggplot(df, aes(.data[[col]], ..count..)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = .data[[col]]), position = "dodge")
}) -> list_plots
```

Comment: Thank you for the answere. But I don't want to develop a seperate function

Comment: What do you mean by 'develop a separate function'? `lapply` is same as `for` loop. You can use the same logic in `for` loop as well. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
aes(get(col,df),..count..))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it's not working for me