# Automatically creating bar plots with percentages for a dataframe selection

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have example data as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# example data frame
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A;B;C", "A;B", "B;C", "A;C", "B", "A;B;C;D"),
  col2 = c("X;Y;Z", "X;Y", "Y;Z", "X;Z", "Z", "W;X;Y;Z"),
  col3 = c("1;2", "1", "2;3", "3", "4;5;6", "7"),
  col4 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  col5 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
)

# select columns to separate
selected_cols <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
```

I would like to convert [the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75856262/8071608) (which does a count):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

lapply(c("col1", "col2"), function(col) {
  separate_rows(df, all_of(col), sep = ";") |>
    ggplot(aes(.data[[col]])) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = .data[[col]]))
})
```

To code that does percentages:

```
lapply(c("col1", "col2"), function(col) {
  separate_rows(df, all_of(col), sep = ";") |>
    ggplot(aes(.data[[col]])) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = .data[[col]])) +
    stat_count(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
})
```

However, that creates some odd graphs, among which is the following one (I just realised it is precisely the same graph where the counts are now percentages in the 100):

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you added a second set of bars with percentages (and no fill) on top of the bars with the counts. To get only the percentages compute them inside `geom_bar` and drop the `stat_count`. Additionally I switched to `after_stat` as using the `..` notation was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

lapply(c("col1", "col2"), function(col) {
  separate_rows(df, all_of(col), sep = ";") |>
    ggplot(aes(.data[[col]])) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count)), fill = .data[[col]])) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
})
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]