# Percentages scores showing up a different distances above the bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have example data as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# example data frame
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A;B;C", "A;B", "B;C", "A;C", "B", "A;B;C;D"),
  col2 = c("X;Y;Z", "X;Y", "Y;Z", "X;Z", "Z", "W;X;Y;Z"),
  col3 = c("1;2", "1", "2;3", "3", "4;5;6", "7"),
  col4 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  col5 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
)

# select columns to separate
selected_cols <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
```

I am using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857612/8071608) to show percentage scores for selected columns:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

lapply(c("col1", "col2"), function(col) {
  separate_rows(df, all_of(col), sep = ";") |>
    ggplot(aes(.data[[col]])) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count)), fill = .data[[col]])) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(after_stat(count/sum(count))), y = after_stat(count/sum(count))), 
          stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = 1.1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
})
#> [[1]]
```

But I am having a hard time to get the percentage scores above the bars at the same distance. As you can see the distance seems to be dependent on the percentage score. Is there any way to change this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you shift the labels with the `vjust` parameter of `position_stack` which is meant to position the labels inside the bars. Second, even if you use the `vjust` argument of `geom_text` the distance will depend on the value. A better approach would be to use `nudge_y`. However, my preferred option for this case would be to use `geom_label` which via the `label.padding` argument allows to set the distance to the bars in absolute units independent of the scale or range of the data. To get the `geom_text` look we have to set `fill=NA` and `label.size=0` to remove the box drawn by default:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

lapply(c("col1", "col2"), function(col) {
  separate_rows(df, all_of(col), sep = ";") |>
    ggplot(aes(.data[[col]])) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count)), fill = .data[[col]])) +
    geom_label(aes(label = scales::percent(after_stat(count / sum(count))), y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),
      stat = "count", vjust = 0,
      label.padding = unit(5, "pt"),
      fill = NA, label.size = 0
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
})
```

[image]